# How to design schema for nested data

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I created a post Schema and I have trouble implementing the comment and comment reply schema since you can not predict how often one comment reply has it own reply.

I am using mongoose and express.

So how can I implement this type of schema design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this where you are referencing comments from within your comment schema.

I added a middleware to pre-populate the replies array when you call `.find()`. You can add more middleware for other calls like `.findOne()` etc.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    comment: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    author: { // To reference the user that left the comment. If needed
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    replies:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment"}] // Array of comment replies
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// Middleware to populate the replies when you call `find()`
commentSchema.pre('find', function() {
  this.populate('replies');
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

You can do more in-depth on this post which will show you how to pre-populate the replies field when returning comments etc.

> https://www.makeschool.com/academy/track/standalone/reddit-clone-in-node-js/comments-on-comments

Comment: thanks for your replay and this is what i am looking for